# Android studio margin effects other items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I try to put a textview top of a button and this button is centered. If I add margin to textview then button shift as well. How can I fix the button and add some margin to textview ?

Here my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    >

   <TableLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <LinearLayout android:layout_marginBottom="100sp"

           >
           <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               >
               <TextView
                   android:text="asdasdasd"
                   android:textColor="@color/black" >

               </TextView>
           </TableRow>
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout >
           <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:background="@color/white">
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button"
                   android:layout_width="100sp"
                   android:layout_height="100sp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                   android:text="Başlat"
                   android:textColor="@color/white" />
           </TableRow>
       </LinearLayout>
   </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a requirement to use RelativeLayout I would suggest using ConstraintLayout.
First, you can set desired positions for the Button, and after setting the text bottom to be constrained to your Button.
After that, you can add margin to your text without being afraid to influence Button position

Your layout can looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="asdasdasd"
                android:textColor="@color/black">

            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:text="Başlat"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS:
Out of the topic of the question, but
I would recommend using `dp` for setting the view size because `sp` is used for defining the size off the text.

Also, both `LinearLayout` and `TableRow` seem redundant and you probably can go directly with `Button` and `TextView`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and answer. I used tableroe due to seperate two elements but it didn't work. As your answer solved my problem, ı can remove them. I had made some research about dp and sp and I see sp is more suitable for responsive design, because of that I used it.

Comment: @Wtow glad it worked for you